# Python - sort method parameter takes same precedence

Tags: python, operator-keyword

In my program I want to order all the contacts by their name, last name first, then by first name.

I've got the code which does that for me *but* it doesn't do it exactly as I want it to.

For example, if I have a list of names ordered as the current code would do, it would go like this:

```
Luke
Riyaan
Amanda Benson
```

As you can see, the code still takes `None` as a value to sort on, what I want is this:

```
Amanda Benson
Luke
Riyaan
```

So basically, if the last name returns `None` then I want the program to order the first name with the same precedence of an object that does have a last name.

Here's the code that I'm currently using to sort the names:

```
import operator

...

addressBook = AddressBook()
addressBook.contactsList
addressBook.contactsList.sort(key = operator.attrgetter("lastName", "firstName"))
```

Comment: What are your contacts? Are they class instances too? Have you implemented the comparison magic methods in the class?

Comment: They are class instances stored in a list. I have no idea what comparison magic methods are/mean, so probably not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a custom sort function then that returns your first name as the first value in a tuple, when the last name is missing:

```
def name_sort(contact):
    if contact.lastName:
        return contact.lastName, contact.firstName
    return contact.firstName, ''

addressBook.contactsList.sort(key=name_sort)
```

You *can* use a `lambda` and conditional expression to fit that into the `sort()` call:

```
addressBook.contactsList.sort(key=lambda c: (c.lastName, c.firstName) if c.lastName else (c.firstName, ''))
```

I produce a 2-value tuple here for both cases, but a one-element tuple for the no-last-name case should suffice too.

If this is the only sort order you are interested in, you may want to look in providing the [rich comparison functions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) so you can sort your objects without a key; the objects *themselves* are then compared and provide the sort order.

You don't have to implement all rich-comparison methods to do so; all you need is *one* of them, plus `__eq__` (equality testing), and the [`@functools.total_ordering()` class decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering):

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Contact(object):
    # ...

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.lastName != other.lastName:
            return False
        return self.firstName == other.firstName

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not self.lastName:
            if not other.lastName:
                return self.firstName < other.firstName
            return self.firstName < other.lastName
        return (self.lastName, self.firstName) < (other.lastName, other.firstName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to implement [the rich comparison magic methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) in your (I guess) `Contact` class:

```
class Contact(object):

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name=""):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def __repr__(self): # to make the demo clearer!
        if not self.last_name:
            return str(self.first_name)
        return "{0.first_name} {0.last_name}".format(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.first_name == other.first_name and 
                self.last_name == other.last_name)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.last_name and other.last_name:
            if self.last_name == other.last_name:
                return self.first_name < other.first_name
            return self.last_name < other.last_name
        else:
            if other.last_name:
                return self.first_name < other.last_name
            return self.first_name < other.first_name
```

Now you can just use `sorted` and `list.sort` without arguments:

```
>>> contacts_list = [Contact("Luke"), Contact("Riyaan"), Contact("Amanda", "Benson")]
>>> sorted(contacts_list)
[Amanda Benson, Luke, Riyaan]
```